# C++ const char* with string literal in method call

Tags: c++, string, string-literals

If I have a C++ function that takes a string parameter:

```
void somefunc(const std::string &s)
{
  std::cout << ": " << s << std::endl;
}
```

If I then have something like:

```
const char *s = "This is a test...";
somefunc(s + "test");
```

I get an error:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char*’ and ‘const char [5]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

How can I call `somefunc` with `s` plus some other string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers (`const char*`) can't be added by `operator+`.

You can make either operand to `std::string`, to concatenate strings.

```
somefunc(std::string(s) + "test");
somefunc(s + std::string("test"));
```

Or use [`std::string` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
somefun(s + "test"s);
//          ^^^^^^^  <- std::string, not const char[5]
```